# Row provided already belongs to a DataGridView control C#

Tags: c#, datagridview

hi i'm trying to move the rows of my DatagridView to a DataGridViewRowCollection, and this collection represents an item from a list of DataGridViewRowCollection called "SacRowsColl ".

Now i'm having an ArgumentOutOfRangeException at 2nd line in the foreach loop, and when i comment the line before it causes another exception "Row provided already belongs to a DataGridView control".

```
     private void ChangeSac_DeselectingTabPage(object sender, TabControlCancelEventArgs e)
     {
        List<DataGridViewRowCollection> SacRowsColl = new List<DataGridViewRowCollection>();

        if (dgv.Rows.Count != 0)
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgv.Rows.OfType<DataGridViewRow>().ToArray())
            {
                dgv.Rows.Remove(row);
                SacRowsColl[0].Add(row);//this line throws an ArgumentOutOfRangeException
            }
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

*No need to re-add row again and again.The row itself keeps track of what DataGridView it is in.*

Answer (score 0):

Every time you are adding the new row to same DataGridViewRowCollection `SacRowsColl[0]`.

You should increment `SacRowsColl` as well

Comment: <SacRowsColl> is a list of <DataGridViewRowCollection>

Comment: SacRowsColl[0] is a collection of rows, what about it